# Magento 2: Getting 404 Not Found with exception on products after migrating

Tags: magento2

**I have recently copied my Magento 2 website onto another server**, created a **new database** and **imported** a copy of the **old/original database**.
Everything seems to work fine, but when I click on a product it gives me **404 not found**.

The `exception.log` shows the

> exception: Item (Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\Status) with the same ID "38" already exists.'

I have **truncated url_rewrites** and ran **reindex** but the error still occurs.

Hope someone can help me out

Answer (score 0):

There must be some duplicate entries in the database table "cataloginventry_stock_item" for both the stores if you have enabled multistore.

Delete those duplicate values from the table.